# How can I create a dummy variable in Python with a condition below or above median?

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

How can I create binary dummy variables in Python which takes the value of `0` when a person’s salary is below the median salary level and is set to `1` otherwise? I don't understand how to make it when salary above or below.

I tried this

```
df['Salary'] = (df['Salary'] > df['Salary'].median()) & (df['Salary'] < df['Salary'].median())
```

But there is no output.

Before that I tried this:

```
df['Salary'].median()
df_Salary = pd.get_dummies(df['Salary'].median())
df_new = pd.concat([df, df_Salary], axis=1)
df_new
```

And got this

```
    Gender  Exp Salary  74000.0

0   Female  15  78200   1
1   Female  12  66400   NaN
2   Female  3   6000    NaN
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can coerce a boolean to an int by just multiplying it by one:

```
df["Median_Compare"] = (df["Salary"] >= df["Salary"].median()) * 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a vectorized comparison and convert the result to an int:

```
>>> df["Median_Compare"] = (df["Salary"] >= df["Salary"].median()).astype(int)
>>> df
   Gender  Exp  Salary  Median_Compare
0  Female   15   78200               1
1  Female   12   66400               0
2  Female    3    6000               0
```

This works because we have

```
>>> df["Salary"].median()
66400.0
>>> df["Salary"] >= df["Salary"].median()
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: Salary, dtype: bool
>>> (df["Salary"] >= df["Salary"].median()).astype(int)
0    1
1    0
2    0
Name: Salary, dtype: int32
```

To make the ternary approaches work (X if (condition) else Y), you'd need to `apply` it because they don't play nicely with arrays, which don't have an unambiguous truth value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this (using your notation and variable names).

```
df['Salary'] = 0 if df['Salary'] < df['Salary'].median() else 1
```

This works exactly like it reads. It says `df['Salary']` will be zero if the salary is less than the median, otherwise make it one. For reference, this type of statement is known as a *ternary operator*.

Comment: Thanks a lot!                                                                                                But when I tried as you said an error occurred                                'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'

Comment: Well then that is a problem with whatever `df['Salary']` and `df['Salary'].median()` is. Without knowing what those are I can't give you more specific help, but it would seem `df['Salary']` is an array of values and python doesn't know how to assess the validity of an array of Trues and Falses. You might need something like list comprehension where you do `df['Salary'] = [0 if salary < df['Salary'].median() else 1 for salary in df['Salary']]`. I'm only guessing at the code though because, like I said, I don't know what your variables are.

Answer (score 0):

This is just using a basic conditional and storing the variable.

```
median = 30500
salary = 50000
median_flag = 1 if salary > median else 0
print median_flag
1
```